# How can I use Google Cloud CDN for static website hosted on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, cloudflare, google-cloud-cdn

I am serving a super simple static website on Google App Engine. I chose the Zurich location which serves content pretty decently within all locations that I tested within Europe. Speed tests that I did online show <1s page load speeds within Europe. In the US, especially west coast, South America, Asia and Australia the page load time is, however, over 3s which is for me not acceptable.

Therefore I thought of using Google Cloud CDN. Unfortunately their CDN seems to require some HTTPS load balancers and I have no idea how to set that up. Seems silly if Google had their own CDN but that doesn't work with their App Engine so I'd have to go to Cloudflare.

Comment: Support for App Engine (and Cloud Run) is coming in the near future. See twitter.com/ahmetb/status/1227653149835448320 for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're not able to use Google Cloud CDN for you site on Google App Engine. Nowadays Cloud CDN could be used to serve content that originates from Cloud Storage buckets, Compute Engine instance groups, and Compute Engine network endpoint groups.

Have a look at the documentation [Overview of Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/overview):

> The Cloud CDN content delivery network works with HTTP(S) load
>   balancing to deliver content to your users. The HTTP(S) load balancer
>   provides the frontend IP addresses and ports that receive requests and
>   the backends that respond to the requests.
>
> Cloud CDN content can be sourced from various types of backends:
>
> - [Instance groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups)
> - [Zonal network endpoint groups (NEGs)](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/zonal-neg-concepts)
> - [Internet network endpoint groups (NEGs) (Beta)](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/internet-neg-concepts), for endpoints that are outside of Google Cloud (also known as custom origins)
> - Buckets in [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs)

I found at Google Public Issue Tracker two feature requests about adding Cloud CDN support for App Engine [Standard](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117145307) and [Flexible](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120472978) - you can join these cases, comment and track progress.

**Possible workaround** for a simple site you can find in this [article](https://medium.com/@marco_37432/create-a-custom-domain-cdn-with-google-beta-7ad9531dfbae).

Comment: Thank you - the workaround might be OK for totally static assets but the scripting capabilities and connection to Google Build with triggers (in our case triggered by GitHub commits to master) in App Engine is actually something that I'd not like to miss.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62660953/4185100 - Soon we can use serverless NEG with HTTPS load balancer for AppEngine and enabling CDN.